# Show that there exists a regular function that is not a quotient of polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Consider the Zariski-closed subset $Y=Z(xw-yz)\subset k^n$. On $U=Y\setminus Z(y,w)$ we consider the function
$$
f\colon U\to k, P=(a,b,c,d)\mapsto 
\begin{cases}
a/b &\text{if $P\in U\setminus Z(y)$,}\\
c/d & \text{if $P\in U\setminus Z(w).$}
\end{cases}
$$
My lectures notes claim that this is an example of a function that cannot be written as $f=g/h$ for $f,g\in k[x,y,z,w]$. I haven't been able to actually prove this. What I checked was that $xw-yz$ is an irreducible polynomial, and hence $Z(xw-yz)$ is irreducible. This would mean that if there were $g,h\in k[x,y,z,w]$, then $x/y=f/g$ on $U\setminus Z(y)$, and hence $xg=yf$ (since $U$ is also irreducible). Likewise $z/w=f/g$ yields $zg=wf$ on $U$. I can't find a contraction using this, which I need. Could someone help me out?

This question has been asked before (e.g. here: [An example of a regular function over an open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149688/an-example-of-a-regular-function-over-an-open-set/149797#149797)), but the accepted answer talks about Cartier divisors, which I haven't seen before, so I'm actually hoping there is a more elementary argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find a contradiction from what you wrote because there isn't one.

In the function field $k[Y] = \mathrm{Frac}(A)$ where $A = k[x,y,z,w]/(xw-yz)$ we do indeed have $\frac{f}{g} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{z}{w}$ exactly because $xw - yz = 0$ and in the function field every nonzero element becomes invertible.

However, you are not asking about *rational functions* (the functions that live in the function field) but about *regular functions* meaning that you must have $\frac{f}{g} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{z}{w}$ in the function field and additionally $g$ vanish nowhere on $U$ so that this fraction produces a well-defined regular function.

Let's see why we must have $g$ vanish somewhere on $U$. We are going to turn this into a pure algebra question. If $g$ did not vanish on $U$ then $Z(g) \subset Z(y,w)$ since $Z(y,w)$ is the complement of $U$. Therefore, $I = (y,w) \subset \sqrt{(g)}$ because these are radical ideals. By Krull's prinicpal ideal theorem $\sqrt{(g)}$ has height $1$ and $I$ is a nonzero prime ideal inside $\sqrt{(g)}$ so $I = \sqrt{(g)}$. Thus $g \in I$ and $I^n = (g)$ for some power $n$.

Let $\mathfrak{m} = (x,y,z,w)$ be the maximal ideal corresponding to the cone point. Now compute that $\dim_{\kappa} I^n_{\mathfrak{m}} / \mathfrak{m} I^n_{\mathfrak{m}} \ge 2$ (think about if $y^n - w^n$ can be in $\mathfrak{m} I^n_{\mathfrak{m}}$) for all $n$ to show that it is impossible for $I^n$ to be principal.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE.** The following proof is incorrect, as indicated in the comment.

I don't think the answer you linked use anything about Cartier divisor.
Note that $f$ is undefined only at points in $Z(y,w)$, so if $f=g/h$
where $g,h\in k[x,y,z,w]$, then
$Z(y,w)=Z(h)$. But this is not possible.

If $y\mid h$ then any $(x,0,z,w)\in k^4$ with $w\ne 0$
lies in $Z(h)$ but not $Z(y,w)$.

If $y\nmid h$.
If $\text{deg}_yh\ge 1$, i.e.
$h= y^nP_n(x,z,w)+\ldots+P_0(x,z,w)$ for $n\ge 1$ and
$0\ne P_n(x,z,w)$. Because $0\ne P_0,P_n$ so $Z(P_0)\cup
Z(P_n)=Z(P_0P_n)\ne k^4$, meaning there exists
$(x_0,z_0,w_0)\in k^3$ s.t. $P_n(x_0,z_0,w_0)\ne 0$
and $P_0(x_0,z_0,w_0)\ne 0$. Thus, $h(x_0,y,z_0,w_0)\in k[y]$
has solution $y'\ne 0$.

If $\text{deg}_yh=0$ and $y\nmid h$, then
$h=h(x,z,w)\ne 0$. If we can find $(x_0,z_0,w_0)$ s.t.
$h=0$, then $(x_0,y,z_0,w_0)\in P(h)$ for any $y\ne 0$,
meaning $P(h)\ne P(y,w)$. Else, $P(h)=\emptyset\ne P(y,w)$.

Comment: Can you explain why we have $Z(y,w)=Z(h)$? To me it seems that all we know is that $Z(xw-yz)-Z(y,w)\subset Z(xw-yz)-Z(h)$. i.e., $Z(xw-yz)\cap Z(h)\subset Z(y,w)$. If that is indeed all we know, then in the case $\operatorname{deg}_y(h)$ we have no guarantee that $(x_0,y',z_0,w_0)\in Z(xw-yz)$, and then the argument doesn't work.

Comment: @ShaVuklia You are right. I forgot that ℎ, should be viewed as functions on . It seems that my argument doesn't work anymore, and I don't know how to fix this.